# Losing data persistence when restart Docker service on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cassandra, windows-10, cassandra-3.0

I'm using Docker (Desktop 2.0.0.3) and Docker-compose (1.23.2) to start 3 services:
1-Postgresql
2-Cassandra
3-My Webapp

The thing is that I'm losing data, just on Cassandra, when I restart Docker service on Windows 10. Do not happen when restart containers, do not happen to PostgreSQL when restart Docker service

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
   version: '3.1' 

cassandra:
    container_name: cassandra
    image: launcher.gcr.io/google/cassandra3
    ports:
       - '7000:7000'
       - '7001:7001'
       - '7199:7199'
       - '9042:9042'
       - '9160:9160'
       - '9404:9404'

    volumes:
      - /home/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra  
      
    restart: always
      
postgresql:
 
    container_name: "postgresql"
    image: postgres:11.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: mydb
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
       - ./startup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/startup.sql 
       - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      
    ports:
        - 5432:5432


volumes:
   postgresql:
   cassandra:
```

I can access properly to container, create keyspaces, launch my app which depends on cassandra to be fully available...

If I restart the Container, created keyspaces and data still there, if I restart Docker service in host, data is erased. Cannot figure out why, quite sure is some kind of typo or something in my yaml